# Post in facebook with APIGRAPH

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, postman, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm trying to make a post on Facebook, using the Graph API, with country restriction.
but I have an error with the location_types field, I am attaching an image of my query in postman.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPZmb.png)

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And if possible, please switch your account language to English, so that we get the error message in English as well.